# Using PreAnalyzedField in Solr 4

Tags: solr

I am trying to index fields using Solr, in which I already have a TokenStream. I dont want Solr to have any analysis - Its already made. As I understood, I could get this exact functionality using Solr's PreAnalyzedField.
The problem is that I cannot find any good resource to help me understand the flow:
I needto define the field in the schema.xml file as PreAnalyzedField, and the tokenstream should be parsed using the parse method of the parser implementation - but how to I actually feed the field with my tokeStream? how \ when exactly is it sent to the toFormattedString method???

Answer (score 0):

I think PreAnalyzedField is a bleeding edge of Solr as of 4.0/4.1. [The main documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/PreAnalyzedField) is on the Wiki and basically explains the two parser types. The default is JSON, I am not sure how to get the other type to work.

Once you have that type defined, you just supply fully-tokenized content in the JSON format as described as that field's value. When that hits the parser, it will convert it to the Token stream. The same way a number gets parsed from a string representation into a real numeric representation. Try feeding an unparsable value and you will see the full call stack in the exception stacktrace.

The problem is how to query it. [My own discussion on the mailing list](http://grokbase.com/t/lucene/solr-user/1313ewa1xk/anybody-uses-preanalyzedfield) did not get very far.

Comment: according to the test (https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/core/src/test/org/apache/solr/schema/PreAnalyzedFieldTest.java), your options for querying it are to specify a query time analysis chain or to put JSON in the query. no way of hooking into query parsers afaict :(